# Unix awk Substring string comparison

Tags: unix, awk

I want to find if a substring is contained in a string using Unix AWK command.

eg, pseudocode:

```
a= commandline
b=line
if(b is contained in a)
  print "success "
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{a="commandline";b="line";if (a ~ b){print "success"}}'
success
```